# Erro no where, na hora de comparar tabelas e gerar um resultado

Tags: php

Estou tendo erros no meu select, estou tentando comparar dois **"id"** de duas tabelas simultaneamente e fazer **COUNT** para gerar o resultado em **id** especifico, quando rodo o script não me da resutado nenhum, vou deixar uma imagem com o script talvez seja melhor a visualização, desde já agradeço.
[print tirada do script que estou usando](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzdXE.png)

Esse escript era para contar quantas curitdas uma postagem em outra tabela recebeu, mais não estou conseguindo capturar o resultado.

Comment: deu certo em partes, ele até gera o meu resultado mais em todos os post ele colocar a mesma quantidade de curtidas, e nem todos os post tem curtida.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Estou vendo que você está fazendo COUNT(curtida), mas o select não sabe de onde ele deve puxar esse campo se é do aliases `ft` ou `lg`, você precisa informar o select qual campo ele precisa contar. Deverá ficar da seguinte forma, por exemplo `COUNT(ft.curtida)`.

No WHERE, você precisa passar qual é a condição, ficaria da seguinte forma por exemplo: `WHERE lg.id = {$idPost}`

Answer (score -3):

Tente da seguinte forma

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela1.id, tabela2.id    
FROM tabela1
INNER JOIN tabela2.id ON tabela1.id = tabela2.id
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigaod Heitor, mais os dois FROM é erro de sintaxe.